# Swapping the value in Table based on Reference in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Input DataFrame: [Input Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XB1Rp.png)

We have to swap the value in input data frame according to the value mentioned in Reference Table. [Ref Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJevP.png) means (A>>1, B>>2, C>>3......)

Desired Output: [Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMVvZ.png)

```
dp1 = dp1.set_index('Ref')
for i in range(df1.shape[1]):
    df1.iloc[:,i] = df1.iloc[:,i].replace(dp1.iloc[:])
```

Join & Merge function does not work in this question.

It is not swapping the input table value. Please suggest where am I getting wrong or alternative method to do?

Comment: It is not a duplicate question @jezrael. The solution which you have suggested does not resolve the problem which I have asked. Please have a look on query.

Comment: OK, please add code from dupe, `merge` and `map` and show why not working. Because it seems not tested.

Comment: Have used map method only with For Loop. It is working fine. Thanks